# grid data according to drop down value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have drop down and grid view..i fill drop down from database like this

There is two table `tblReg` and `tblRes`  both have RegionID

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            T1 tea = new T1();
            var list1 = tea.tblReg.ToList();
            var list = (from ta in list1
                        let data = ta.Region + " " + ta.StartDate ?? DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ta.EndDate ?? DateTime.Now.ToString()
                        select new { data, ta.RegionID }).ToList();

            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                regiondrop.DataSource = list;
                regiondrop.DataTextField = "data";
                regiondrop.DataValueField = "RegionID";
                regiondrop.DataBind();

            }
    }
```

now there is several values in drop down and i want when i select value from drop down then again to this value data will be display

On dropdown SelectedIndexChange i done this

```
 protected void regiondrop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        T1 ts = new T1();

        var dq=(from dropdwn in ts.tblRes
               where dropdwn.RegionID==Convert.ToInt32(regiondrop.SelectedValue)
               orderby dropdwn.OwnerName
               select new {
                            FFID = dropdwn.FFID,
                            OwnerName = dropdwn.OwnerName,
                            RegNo = dropdwn.RegNo,
                            RegionID = dropdwn.RegionID,

               });
        GridView1.DataSource = dq;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

when i select value from dropdown it shows error

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

on

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

any solution

Comment: Is `SelectedIndexChanged` event triggering?

Comment: make sure AutoPostBack is set to true in your ASPX markup.

Comment: AutoPostBack is true on gridview

Comment: It should be true on `dropdown` not gridview.

Comment: yes AutoPostBack is also true on dropdown

Comment: it shows error :LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. on gridview.batabind();

Comment: check update question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as your error mentions, you can't do

```
Convert.ToInt32(regiondrop.SelectedValue)
```

in a linq to entities query (it can't be translated in sql / a store expression)

So just change these lines

```
var dq=(from dropdwn in ts.tblRes
        where dropdwn.RegionID==Convert.ToInt32(regiondrop.SelectedValue)
```

to

```
var selectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(regiondrop.SelectedValue);

var dq=(from dropdwn in ts.tblRes
            where dropdwn.RegionID==selectedValue
```

You could also do (but the previous solution is more readable)

```
var dq=(from dropdwn in ts.tblRes
            where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)dropdwn.RegionID)==regiondrop.SelectedValue
```

There's a method  in `SqlFunctions` to convert a numeric to a string, but... not a string to a numeric value.